# Como executar tarefas assíncronas no PHP?

Tags: php, async

Eu tenho um sistema de loja virtual simples, onde o cliente faz um pedido de determinados produtos e o sistema registra isso, no momento em que o cliente registra o pedido o sistema envia uma mensagem de e-mail e também se comunica com uma API passando os dados do pedido. O problema é que este processo todo esta demorando muito tempo para ser executado para que então eu possa dar uma resposta de sucesso para o cliente. O ato de enviar o email e se comunicar  com a API não são obrigatórios para que eu de uma resposta de sucesso para o cliente.

Tendo explicado a minha situação, eu queria que o sistema fosse capaz de registrar o pedido do cliente e imediatamente retornar a resposta de sucesso, e posteriormente realizar as ações de enviar o email e se comunicar com a API.

Eu tive duas idéias, porém não achei uma solução para elas:

1 - A primeira ideia seria retornar a resposta para o cliente e continuar com o resto do script sem que a minha pagina ficasse agarrada com estas ações. Acontece que atualmente o meu script php só retorna a mensagem para o cliente quando ele termina todas as tarefas (enviar email e API).

Ex: Cliente faz pedido->Sistema registra pedido->Sistema responde o cliente [Fim de comunicação com o cliente]->Sistema envia e-mail ->Sistema comunica API

2 - A segunda alternativa era criar algo semelhante a threads, porém como se trata de uma WebAPP o meu servidor Apache não suporta o pthreads.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma solução para este problema.

---

Código PHP que estou utilizando:

```
// Funcao registra pedido 
$resultado = registraPedido($_POST);
if ($resultado) {
  //Funcao envia e-mail 
  enviaEmail($resultado);
  //Funcao comunica API 
  comunicaAPI($resultado);
  echo 'SUCESSO';
} else {
  echo 'ERRO';
}
```

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio - Eu não preciso do e-mail para confirmar o pedido, ele servira apenas como um extra, por isso o ato de registrar o pedido não necessita necessariamente desta etapa, podendo ser feita apos a resposta dada ao cliente.

Comment: Acontece que a chamada as funções do email e a da comunicação com a API devem ser feitas através do PHP por critérios de segurança. Neste caso, eu faço uma chama Ajax a um script "pedido.php" por exemplo, e este registra o pedido, chama a função do email e a função da API. Eu queria dar a resposta a chamada AJAX e continuar executando as outras função no PHP sem que a pagina tivesse que ficar esperando o fim do script

Comment: A chamada eu faço por ajax, porem nao pode ser async pois eu preciso da confirmação de que o registro foi salvo

Comment: Como eu disse antes, eu não posso realizar a chamada do email e da API pelo Ajax por motivos de segurança do projeto, sendo assim teria que ser alguma alternativa no server side. Existe alguma forma de forçar a resposta do script ao cliente e ainda assim continuar executando o script sem que travasse a chamada Ajax?

Comment: E se após a resposta do `AJAX`, você fizesse outra requisição `AJAX` para ele executar as outras funções? Por exemplo: o cliente fez o pedido e voltou uma resposta de sucesso, e ai desce um box de confirmação do pedido e na hr que ele clicar em `OK`, vc por via `AJAX` mandesse executar as outras duas funções?

Comment: essa função `comunicaAPI` deveria seguir essa mesma logica de async? `registraPedido` é a unica operação que não pode ser async pelo que eu entendi, certo?

Comment: Correto, a registra pedido é a principal, após ela a mensagem de sucesso deve ser retornada para o cliente, já  a enviaEmail e comunicaAPI devem ser async para não travar a resposta. Eu tentei utilizar esta solução http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273570/continue-processing-php-after-sending-http-response porém nao funcionou.

Comment: Vou dar uma pensada melhor no seu problema, tentar criar um exemplo minimo aqui

Comment: @RuhanDeOliveiraBaiense seu PHP está rodando em qual Sistema Operacional, GNU/Linux?

Comment: A aplicação está rodando numa hospedagem Linux, com Apache, porém como é uma revenda, eu só tenho acesso as configurações pelo cPanel

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Marcelo,

*...no momento em que o cliente registra o pedido o sistema envia uma mensagem de e-mail e também se comunica com uma API passando os dados do pedido. O problema é que este processo todo esta demorando muito tempo para ser executado para que então eu possa dar uma resposta de sucesso para o cliente.*

Também já tive o mesmo problema e aprendi que não podemos depender de recursos externos como servidor SMTP, **então sugiro você disparar estas ações como processos em background**, aqui para mim resolveu perfeitamente.

Exemplo no GNU/Linux:

exec("php index.php envia_email/EnviaEmailPedido index {$pedi->idPedido} > /dev/null 2>&1 &");

Onde a parte que realmente importa é o fim do comando `> /dev/null 2>&1 &`

Desta forma você tem um processo em background (ou assíncrono ao seu processo principal no Apache, o site com a interface gráfica) que pode demorar mais tempo sem preocupações, inclusive no envio de emails pode tentar enviar N vezes caso a primeira tentativa falhe.